# WPF listview remove extra column generated

Tags: wpf, listview

When I use a ListView in WPF it always generates one extra column at the end of the ListView. For example, if I define two columns in my listview and when I run it it generates those two columns plus one empty column header. Any idea how I can remove that?

Sample ListView XAML

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SearchAttributes}"
                      DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView x:Name="grdView">
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SearchFieldName}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Balance" Width="Auto"
                                        CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource searchFilterDataTemplateSelector}"
                                        >
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

Thanks,
Jithu

Answer (score 1):

The last column is simply the left over space you need to size the columns to fit exactly in the space. By defining the width as Auto you are making sure that is only as big as possible.

Answer (score -3):

There should be a property in GridView, something like AutoGenerateColumns - set it to "False"

Comment: AutoGenerateColumn is part of DataGrid and is not part of GridView and ListView.